# How to Read Azure Storage Key

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure storage connection string and from which I want to read *AccountName* and *Account Key*.
I could get the *account Name* but not the *key*.
Can anyone suggest me how to read *Key*?

> ConnectionString : DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=dev;AccountKey=tsdsgyduysaugdsay4aR6EPn2Ie9YOILeEp5RRFXeeaJ9;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

```
var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);

var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(cloudStorageAccount.Credentials.AccountName, cloudStorageAccount.Credentials.KeyName);
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Once you have an instance of CloudStorageAccount, you can perform all storage operations.

Comment: I want to create CloudBlockBlob object with fileUri and storage credentials

Comment: I think it will not be presented because it would lay in memory for no reason. Normally the key is part of the connection string or is put to the config. Would be good to know what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Just use `cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()` and so on. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-portal

Comment: How can I do GetBlockBlobReference with full URL?

Comment: Tried below code:                                                                                                 
     var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("ConectionString");
            var blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("blobFullUri");
            return container.GetBlockBlobReference(uri);

Comment: So you can use storage credentials property of storage account. Why create a new object?

Answer (score 1):

So if you have storage credentials (account name and key) and the blob's URI, there're two ways to create an instance of CloudBlockBlob.

```
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;");
        var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://account-name.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/blob-name"), storageAccount.Credentials);
```

OR

```
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;");
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://account-name.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/blob-name"), blobClient);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need to use the `ExportBase64EncodedKey()` method to extract the key and even then it's hidden from debug:

```cs
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_connectionString);
var credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(storageAccount.Credentials.AccountName, storageAccount.Credentials.ExportBase64EncodedKey());
```